# Event ingestion and query ability

Tags: database, events, architecture

I need to put in place a system, in which I need to ingest a events (emails, page visits, page events, etc.) and at the same time I need to ensure I'm able to analyse and build reports on top of that data set. At this point I expect something under 100 events per second.

I'll most likely use AWS services to implement this.

Can you give me some suggestions on possible architectures for this.

The first one I can think off is to have an API Gateway endpoint receiving the events, connected to a lambda expression that then inserts data into Redshift.

Other alternative would be to use kinesis streams and load them directly to Redshift.

If done like this will Redshift allow me to still querying the data in real time without having locking issues?

What other alternatives can you suggest? I was also taking a look into Google Query.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at snow plow analytics.

Comment: Meanwhile I found SnowPlow.